# Can't import opencv when executing my script from command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

When I'm trying to execute my script from the command prompt I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

In the same time I can import and use it from Spyder. Any advises where to dig?

P.S. Win10, my Path environment variable already includes:

```
C:\Anaconda3
C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably caused by Spyder using a different version of python.

Try this in terminal:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```